# VB.NET : How to arrange IBlobFieldObject (Image) in crystal report

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I manage to display an image in crystal report by fetching the data in the database

OUTPUT:
[image]

But I want to arrange the images like this

[image]

I can't seem to find any way how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you are using the details section and each photo is in a different row of the data source. If that's the case, you need to right click the section, choose "section expert", and mark "format with multiple columns". Then, use the tab "layout" to adjust the width of each column.

Comment: Found a solution somewhere same as yours, and I am satisfied with the output. I'll accept this as an answer. THANKS!